# Redirect multiple URLs using Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, worker

I got a use case where I need to redirect multiple subdomains to their respective destinations, for eg. alpha.domain.com -> www.domain.com/alpha, and external.domain.com -> www.external.com.

I have looked up on this https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/templates/pages/bulk_redirects/ however this is catered for path redirection. I ran out of idea on how to modify it to fit my use case. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
    let requestURL = new URL(request.url)
    let sourceURL = requestURL[1]
    let destination = redirectMap.get(path)
    if (requestURL) {
        return Response.redirect(destination, 301)
    }
}

addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

const redirectMap = new Map([
    ['alpha.domain.com', 'https://www.example.com/alpha/'],
    ['external.domain.com', 'https://www.example.com/'],   

])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `requestURL.host` To put it all together you will need something like this:

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
    let requestURL = new URL(request.url);
    let destination = redirects[requestURL.host];
    if (destination) {
        return Response.redirect(destination, 301);
    }
    //determine what do do if there is no host match here
    return Response.redirect('https://www.default.com', 301);
}

addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

const redirects = {
  'alpha.domain.com' : 'https://www.example.com/alpha/',
  'external.domain.com' : 'https://www.example.com/'
}
```